# Make voice call using Twilio Client JS, a subaccount and access token

Tags: twilio, twilio-programmable-voice, twilio-javascript

I am trying to make a voice call from a subaccount and keep getting the error:

```
callerId must be provided for TwilioClient and SIP calls when using Dial
```

I have verified my application SID, Account SID, api key SID and secret and all match up.  The body of the response logged in the Twilio debugger is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Response>
    <Dial answerOnBridge="true" callerId="PHONE NUMBER OF PARENT ACCOUNT">
        <Number>THE PHONE NUMBER IM TRYING TO CALL (A REAL PHONE)</Number>
    </Dial>
</Response>
```

I cant find anywhere in the docs that show this with the JS library.  I have tried setting the `From` field in the options for `Device.connect` with no luck.
Do i have to specify anything for the voice grants?

Another odd thing, everything works if I dial from the parent account's number, but When i go and look at the parent account, it doesnt have voice enabled.

Comment: To clarify, the callerID # you've tried is a Twilio phone #?

Comment: I dont even know where to specify the callerId.  If I specify a From, it doesnt help.

Comment: the `callerId` attribute in the <Dial> tag?

Comment: @lizziepika Im using the JS client.  There is no XML/TWIML used (there is no Dial tag)

Comment: What's your JS code? You can pass twiml to the js client ie. `client.calls
      .create({
         twiml: '<Response><Say>Ahoy, World!</Say></Response>',
         to: PHONE-NUM-TO-CALL
         from: 'TWILIO-NUM'
       })
      .then(call => console.log(call.sid));`

here is using `callerId` with `Dial`
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60738484/how-to-use-twiml-to-connect-calls

Comment: @lizziepika TwilioClient JS doesnt have a a calls property.

Comment: can you include your JavaScript code? That would probably help